# CSS dropdown menu z-index struggling

Tags: jquery, html, css

What's wrong with our css dropdown?
When I mouse-over on "Servizi" it should extend much more down... I've been struggling with z-index... what is wrong?

http://tickmark.edoardobiasini.it

Thanks..

Comment: you certianly have a LOT of duplicated css in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the z-indexes - but you do have set `overflow:hidden` on your `<nav>`-element (see line 385 in style.css).

Comment: yep, overflow problem. set to :visible